# facet_grid and facet_wrap change the axis scale when it is a percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw histograms for each year but when I use facet_grid or facet_wrap the percentages of the y-axis change.
you can download the data from [here](https://gssdataexplorer.norc.org/projects/48806/extracts/35817).

Normal use:

```
data <- gss %>% 
  select(year, educ, race) %>%
  filter(race!="Other", year %in% 1972:1977)

ggplot(data %>% filter(year == 1972)) +
  geom_histogram(data = data %>% filter(race=="Black"), 
                 aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), x=educ, fill="green"), alpha =.5) +
  geom_histogram(data = data %>% filter(race=="White"),
                 aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), x=educ, fill="red"), alpha =.5)
```

[image]

facet:

```
ggplot(data)+
  geom_histogram(data = data %>% filter(race=="Black"), 
                 aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), x=educ, fill="green"), alpha =.5) +
  geom_histogram(data = data %>% filter(race=="White"),
                 aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), x=educ, fill="red"), alpha =.5) + 
  facet_grid (. ~ year, scales = "free")
```

[image]

How to prevent axis change when using `facet_grid`?

Comment: semi off-topic: you shouldn't filter your data twice but instead set `fill = race` in `geom_histogram` once.

Comment: on-topic: calculate the percentage values for each year, not the for the entire period from 1972 to 1975.

Comment: off-topic as well: Check your fill values. These aren't the colours you intended. You may want to check out `scale_fill_manual()`'s use cases, if you haven't used it before.